# Designing a Modular Algorithmic Trading System: The Need for Centralized Configuration

Tags: python, configuration

**Project Overview:**

I'm in the process of developing a comprehensive Python-based algorithmic trading system. My system is organized into various components, each with a distinct function, and I've hosted these on GitHub as submodules within a main repository. Here's a breakdown of these components:

1. **Polygon.io API Wrapper**: This component fetches stock market data by interacting with the Polygon.io API.
2. **InfluxDB Custom Interface**: I've designed a customized library that I use to write to and query data from InfluxDB.
3. **Models Repository**: This repository houses all the prediction or analytical models I use to evaluate stock data.
4. **Backtesting Module**: This module allows me to historically test my trading strategies using the models.
5. **Live Trading Interface**: I use this to place real-time stock trades based on insights derived from the models.

**Central Configuration Need:**

I need a unified configuration system to make the system streamlined and more manageable. My goals are to:

- Achieve consistent access to services like Polygon.io and InfluxDB across all submodules.
- Centralize the parameters for models, which are vital for both backtesting and live trading.
- Simplify deployment. Since some parts of my system will be dockerized and hosted on servers while others might run locally, I need to maintain consistent configurations irrespective of the deployment setting.

**Challenges with Existing Solutions:**

I considered `setuptools` for this centralized configuration, but it doesn't offer the flexibility I need. Also, I have thought creating a submodule just for the configuration. Something I can pull or push commit to have the updated version. I have some sensible information. Not sure again for that solution.

**What I'm Looking For:**

A solution that provides a centralized configuration that's easily accessible by all submodules, can be deployed in various settings, and maintains consistency regardless of whether components are run on local machines or dockerized servers.